# C# AES returning incorrect result despite providing same Key and IV to both encryption and decryption functions

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out why my decrypted bytearray and stream is not the same as the unencrypted bytearray.

I thought at first it was because I was encrypting the IV's accidentally, but after changing the code to make sure they are written in plain text and read from that plain text, I'm still getting wildly different results and it's leading to incorrect data being read.

Next I thought that the IV might still be at the start of my data, and that was messing up my ReadBinaryData function but that wasn't the case.

Like I'm getting a file size in the millions of bytes and a map size in the 10s of millions, it should be ~252k bytes and a map size of 5.

I have the 3 following methods:

First a save method:

```
 private bool SaveEncryptedResources(string filePath, string key)
{
    //validation for filePath and key occur earlier
    using (var aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        aes.Key = TransformKey(key);
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        //Removed Key size per Etienne
        aes.GenerateIV();

        byte[] binaryBuffer;

        //Have to write to byte[] because there is some jumping around in WriteBinaryData(); 
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(ms))
            {
                var startPosition = aes.IV.Length;
                WriteBinaryData(bw, startPosition);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                binaryBuffer = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        
        using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            fs.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length);
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(fs, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(cs))
                {
                    bw.Write(binaryBuffer);
                    bw.Flush();
                    cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Second a load method:

```
private void LoadEncryptedResources(string filePath, string key)
{
    byte[] binaryBuffer;
    using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (var aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = TransformKey(key);
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            //Removed Key size per Etienne
            var iv = new byte[aes.IV.Length];
            var numBytesToRead = aes.IV.Length;
            var currentByte = 0;
            //read the IV
            while (numBytesToRead > 0)
            {
                var n = fs.Read(iv, currentByte, numBytesToRead);
                if (n == 0) break;

                currentByte += n;
                numBytesToRead -= n;
            }

            aes.IV = iv;

            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(fs, aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                binaryBuffer = new byte[(int)fs.Length];
                
                //Read returns the number of bytes read and can be used to validate
                //that we actually read the entire file into our buffer
                var bytesRead  = cs.Read(binaryBuffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
            }
        }
    }
    //load binary data into class Stream object
    ResourceStream = new MemoryStream(binaryBuffer);
}
```

Lastly, a read method:

```
private void ReadBinaryData(int startPosition = 0)
{
    //IV doesn't actually appear to be in binary data, so start position is not needed

    var br = new BinaryReader(ResourceStream);
    var fileSize = br.ReadInt32();
    var mapSize = br.ReadInt32();
    //*** Exception no longer thrown, but getting garbled data such as "E:\Proj�� \C#\PixelSharper\PixelSharper.Core\CoreConfiguration.cs" ***.//
    for (var i = 0; i < mapSize; i++)
    {
        var resourceName = br.ReadString();
        var resourceSize = br.ReadInt32();
        var resourceOffset = br.ReadInt32();
        //populate fileMap with file data
        FileMap[resourceName] = new ResourceFile(resourceSize, resourceOffset);
    }
}
```

Oh and here's the key transformation as well:

```
 private static readonly byte[] Salt =
    new byte[] { 2, 3, 16, 125, 21, 232, 4, 189 };

 private static byte[] TransformKey(string password, int keyBytes = 32)
{
    //TODO: make this configurable
    const int iterations = 655360;
    var keyGenerator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Salt,
                                              iterations, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512);
    //KeyBytes are 32*8 = 256 bits for AES
    return keyGenerator.GetBytes(keyBytes);
}
```

Adding WriteBinaryData:

```
    private void WriteBinaryData(BinaryWriter bw, int startPosition = 0)
{
    //Binary Writer inherently knows the size of the type and will write the expected
    //number of bytes to the stream

    var resourceKeys = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    var resourceFileSize = 0;
    bw.Write(resourceFileSize);
    var mapSize = FileMap.Count;
    bw.Write(mapSize);

    //Write the File Map
    foreach (var resource in FileMap)
    {
        //C# binary writer prefixes string with their length
        bw.Write(resource.Key);
        bw.Write(resource.Value.ResourceSize);
        //store start position of resource offset so that we can repopulate
        //the offset with the start position of the actual file data
        resourceKeys.Add(resource.Key, (int)bw.BaseStream.Position);
        bw.Write(resource.Value.ResourceOffset);
        bw.Flush();
    }

    //Write the File Data to the resource file
    var position = bw.BaseStream.Position;
    var keys = FileMap.Keys.ToList();
    foreach (var resource in keys)
    {
        var resourceFile = FileMap[resource];
        //With how the IV is written and read we no longer need to worry about the start position 
        resourceFile.ResourceOffset = (int)position;
        FileMap[resource] = resourceFile;

        //TODO: replace with streaming file read in case the file is too large to fit in memory
        var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(resource);
        bw.Write(fileBytes);
        position = bw.BaseStream.Position;
        bw.Flush();
    }


    //Exclude IV from the total size of the resource file?
    resourceFileSize = (int)bw.BaseStream.Length;
    
    //Update the resource file size from 0 to the current length
    bw.Seek(startPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    bw.Write(resourceFileSize);
    bw.Flush();

    //Update resource file offsets at the positions we recorded in the resourceKeys dictionary,
    //with the updated offsets stored in the FileMap 
    foreach (var resource in FileMap)
    {
        var offsetPosition = resourceKeys[resource.Key];
        bw.Seek(offsetPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        bw.Write(resource.Value.ResourceOffset);
        bw.Flush();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Aren't you basically writing the key, and then a set of 0 bytes the same length as the key, and then the data? Or are you doing something else with `startPosition`?

Comment: Start Position was added to compensate for the length of the IV and to use as an offset for the file offsets, but it turned out not to be needed. 

I'm writing a set of four 0 bytes, the size of an integer, and then updating those 4 bytes after all the data has been written to the file and I can get the position of the stream for the file size. The same is done for the fileoffsets.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama actually, thank you, that was one of the issues, I was using StartPosition = 16 when writing out the data and that was overwriting one byte in my filepath. If you want to add an answer I will accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a tidbit you might have missed from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.keysize):

> Changing the KeySize value resets the key and generates a new random key. This happens whenever the KeySize property setter is invoked (including when it's assigned the same value).

This is common to all symmetric algorithm implementations in .NET.

When you set `KeySize`:

```
aes.KeySize = 256;
```

You do it after setting the key, so a new key is randomly generated, breaking everything. Anyway, you don't need to explicitly set the key size: just set a key with a valid size.

Comment: Removing the aes.KeySize removed the exception but not the garbled data. For example : E:\Proj�� \C#\PixelSharper\PixelSharper.Core\CoreConfiguration.cs

Comment: How do you write data in `WriteBinaryData`?

Comment: I don't think there's an issue there. I have added it just in case, but when I debug it and write out the unencrypted version to disk it's all correct.

Comment: Oh ProgrammingLlama helped with this, the issue was that I was still passing in startPosition even though it was no longer needed.

Comment: So, as I suspected, the issue _was_ in `WriteBinaryData`.